# Proving that PDF of a random variable is given by $\frac{l}{\pi(l^2+t^2)}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm solving the following exercise in "Problems of probability theory by Sveshnikov".

A straight line is drawn at random through the point $(0,l$) in the plane. Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the distance between the $x$-intercept of this line and the origin. Show that the probability density function of $X$ is given by $$f_X(t) = \frac{l}{\pi(l^2+t^2)}$$

My attempt was to first assume that $\theta$ the angle between the line and the line $y = a$ is uniformaly distributed over the interval $(0,\pi)$ so we have $X = a \tan(\theta)$. Then intergrating the density function $\frac{1}{\pi} \mathbb{1}_{(0,\pi)}$, but my solution is still not correct. Not sure where I went wrong. Any hint/help? Thanks.

**Edit:** I tried to get CDF first $$F_X(t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(\theta \leq \arctan(t/a)) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\arctan(t/a)} \mathbb{1}_{(0,\pi)}(s) \ \text{d}s$$

I think my confusion is in re-writing the bounds of the integral, I  re-wrote as $\int_{0}^{\arctan(t/a)}$ and got $1/\pi \arctan(t/a)$ which of course gives the wrong derivative $F' = f$.

Comment: Your attempt sounds good. Could you add some details so that we can find what went wrong?

Comment: Sure, just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ denote angle between the random line and line $y = l$. Than $\theta \sim Uni[0, \pi]$ and $p_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}, \ x \in [0, \pi]$. $X = \frac{l}{\tan \theta}$. By the change of variables formula we get: $p_{X}(y) = p_{\theta}(x^{-1}(y)) \cdot |x^{-1}(y)^{\prime}|$. $y = \frac{l}{\tan x} \Rightarrow x = \arctan \left( \frac{l}{y} \right), \quad x^{-1}(y)^{\prime} = \frac{-l}{y^2 + l^2}$.

So we have: $p_{X}(y) = \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{l}{y^2 + l^2}, \ y \in (-\infty, +\infty)$.

The granzes for $X$ are given from equation: $X = \frac{l}{\tan \theta}$. $X(\theta = 0) = + \infty, \ X(\theta = \pi) = -\infty$